# HTML5 image drag event - ctrlKey remains false in Firefox 29

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop

This works great in Chrome, but what do I need to change to make it work in Firefox?

`e.ctrlKey` remains false in FF:

```
$('img').on('drag', function(e){
    console.log('ctrlKey', e.ctrlKey);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YF6UG/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a bug in Firefox. After some digging in [Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/buglist.cgi?component=Event%20Handling&product=Core&bug_status=__open__) I found unconfirmed bug similar to your problem titled [DragEnd event does not reflect real ctrl/shift/alt key status](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=606885).

Comment: Yea I found that as well. Was hoping for a solution though, but I guess I'll just have to wait

Answer (score 0):

It seems you can detect the ctrlKey in startdrag event, so as a workaround, you can just `$(event.dataTransfer.setData('ctrlKey',event.ctrlKey)` in startdrag. Then you can read it by `$(event.dataTransfer.getData('ctrlKey')` inside dragEnd event